# I need to detect the color (red) in only a small area of screen (i can figure out coordinates). (python)

Tags: python, rgb, color-detection

Me and some of my friends have been working on a program the past couple weeks and this is basically the last thing we couldn't figure out. We need to detect the color (red) in only a small area of screen (i can figure out coordinates). It has to check every 3-5 seconds and return true or something because if it does i either need to close the window, shut down my computer or stop running the rest of the script.

Comment: Can you be a little specific as to why are you doing this exactly and what code have you tried so far would be helpful in us being able to answer your question.

Comment: We are all cs or engineering students and wanted to do a project for fun so we made a macro in a game to do do some complicated but repetitive tasks and there is something on the screen we need to take input from(when it turns red). The rest of the code doesn't take inputs, we just measured where to click, what to type and how to move so we don't really know how to do this and because of that we haven't really tried anything that came close to working.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what you are wanting your program to do...

[OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) is probably the most generic choice.

If you want to automate a task you could use [PyAutoGui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) instead. It includes utilities to control your mouse and keyboard.

If you just want to know the pixel color at a certain location/coordinate then [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/PixelAccess.html) is probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a screenshot with `pyautogui` and process the image with `Pillow`. This approach may be overkill  for your purposes, but could be perfect other others, especially if you want to get other information from the screen at that particular moment.

Sample code to take a screenshot and get the colour of that pixel.

```
from PIL import Image
import pyautogui
myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
myScreenshot.save(r'C:\Users\matthew.gaiser\PycharmProjects\stackoverflow37\screenshot.png')
image = Image.open(r'C:\Users\matthew.gaiser\PycharmProjects\stackoverflow37\screenshot.png')
picture = image.load()
print(picture[20,40])
```

Just delete the image after grabbing the pixel from that particular location.